# Marionette best way to do self render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Hello here is my little code :

i don't know how to make this more marionette ... the save function is too much like backbone...

```
 self.model.save(null, {
        success: function(){
            self.render();
            var vFormSuccess = new VFormSuccess();
            this.$(".return").html(vFormSuccess.render().$el);
        }
var VFormSuccess = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#form-success"
```

} );

http://jsfiddle.net/Yazpj/724/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be using events to show your success view, as well as using a layout to show your success view, if it's going into a different location.

```
MyLayout = Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: "#layout-template",
    regions: {
        form: ".form",
        notification: ".return"
    }
    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.model,'sync',this.showSuccess);
        this.form.show(new FormView({model: this.model}));
    },
    showSuccess: function () {
        this.notification.show(new VFormSuccess());
    } 
});
```

Or, you could do the same with just the one region, and having the FormView be the layout itself. You just need to ensure there is an element matching the notification region exists in the `layout-template`.

```
MyLayout = Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: "#layout-template",
    regions: {
        notification: ".return"
    }
    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.model,'sync',this.showSuccess);
    },
    showSuccess: function () {
        this.notification.show(new VFormSuccess());
    } 
});
```

**What this allows you to do:**

You can then show an error view quite easily, if you wanted. You could replace `initialize` with

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.model,'sync',this.showSuccess);
    this.listenTo(this.model,'error',this.showError);
},
```

and then add the following, ensuring you create a VFormError view.

```
showError: function () {
    this.notification.show(new VFormError());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write

```
self.model.save(null, {
  success: function(){
    self.render();
  }
  ...
```

Why are you doing this

```
this.$(".return").html(vFormSuccess.render().$el);
```

If you define that template as the view template you could simply refer to it with `$el`, if you need two different templates then you might think about using a [Controller](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.controller.md), to decide what to use and who to use it.

Comment: Hello thankyou for anwering! When i do just self.render() (and adding tag :'.return' in my view) nothing append... Maybe because i don't have region?

Comment: Regions are you uset by `Layout` to show views in certain elements, I think you should add more code if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Marionette, you don't call render directly but instead use Marionette.Region to show your views.

Comment: Ok so if i want it to work with a simple self.render() i sould had region?